# DatetimeFieldOverflow when inserting more than three decimals precision

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

`TIMESTAMP` type should be fine ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE))

> timestamp [ (p) ] [ without time zone ]   8 bytes     both date and time (no time zone)   1 microsecond / 14 digits

Create the table like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS l12(
    timestamp TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL,
```

But what I get is

```
psycopg2.errors.DatetimeFieldOverflow: date/time field value out of range: "2019-05-23 12:16:50.954276"
```

When I remove the last three numbers `2019-05-23 12:16:50.954276`--> `2019-05-23 12:16:50.954` **the insert works**.

So is it possible to save a datetime with six decimals precision into one postgresql field?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/245407/datetimefieldoverflow-when-inserting-more-than-three-decimals-precision/245410#comment484358_245407), I found the problem. The error has been on client-side, because I used the following in the INSERT function:

```
INSERT INTO l12 VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-05-23 12:16:50.954276', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ms'))
```

which fails with the mentioned `ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2019-05-23 12:16:50.954276"`

Just remove that `TO_TIMESTAMP` function and be happy or use [`'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.msus`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html) as the correct formating input.